# Auto-Submit/Refresh InfoPath form After Last Field is Entered

Tags: javascript, html, forms, sharepoint, infopath

I'm creating a simple inventory tracking system with scanners and barcodes. I am using InfoPath 2013 to create a form that will update a SharePoint List.

My form has two fields: Location and StockNumber. A barcode scanner will scan a barcode to populate the Location; I have a rule in place to automatically move to StockNumber once Location is filled.

Then the StockNumber barcode is scanned, it populates the StockNumber field, and the focus moves on to the submit button.

As of now, the user would have to click submit or press Enter on their keyboard to save the entry and see a new form.

I would like for the form to submit the data and refresh the form automatically once the StockNumber field is entered. I'm trying to automate this process as much as possible to ensure compliance.

I've seen some answers on using JavaScript in this instance but don't know how I would implement in this situation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've since researched how to do this using an HTML webpart in SharePoint instead of InfoPath since it seems as though JavaScript can more easily be used. Let me know if anyone thinks this may be a more viable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the postback settings to refresh the form and also can submit the data if the value of Field changes. closing the form is a catch, you can only have that on buttons. One thing you can try is to trigger a field value change event or try to set the condition for submit button to trigger on field change.